# arm64 - how to debug EXC_BAD_ACCESS with LLDB

Tags: c++, lldb

Hello I use MacBook M1 (OSX) and I have a dangling pointer which it seems I can't catch.

I am using Clion and LLDB as a debuger.

When I run my code I get:

```
Exception: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x18)
```

However this does not really shows me or I can't understand where exactly is the bad pointer.

I am attaching also screenshot of my editor and the debugger window:

[image]

I have read something about zombie objects which when enabled allows you to catch dangling pointers. How can I do that?

Comment: Someone with your amount of rep should know that posting pictures is not recommended. For example, I am unable to see it. What you should be attempting is running your code through a debugger, assuming this is a run-time issue.

Answer (score 3):

`EXC_BAD_ACCESS` (defined in /usr/include/mach/exception_types.h) has a code (which is a kern_return_t) and a subcode.  `kern_return_t` is defined in /usr/include/mach/kern_return.h and 1 means `KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS`, so this was not a protection problem but an actual invalid address access.  The subcode (0x18) is the address accessed.

A small number like 0x18 usually means that your code accessed a field that was 0x18 bytes into an object, but the object pointer was null.  So the first thing to do is look at all the accesses in that line of code (or around it if you are debugging optimized code) and make sure none of them are null.  This might also be a null vtable, and the 0x18 the vtable offset, i.e. one of the methods of the object, so look for calls as well.  However, I didn't see any suspicious looking pointer values in your locals, so maybe it's some subobject?

If it isn't obvious from there which pointer is bad, you could run your code under ASAN (address sanitizer) - if the bad pointer access is because of a use after free ASAN will often find those quickly.  Note, Zombie objects is an ObjC only thing, that doesn't look relevant in your code.

If that doesn't get it, the most straightforward way to diagnose this sort of error is to look at the disassembly, for instance just run:

(lldb) disassemble

The current PC will be marked in the output.  That instruction will be some kind of memory access, often dereferencing a register with an offset or something like that.  For instance:

```
ldr    w9, [x9, #0x18]
```

is loading memory 0x18 bytes off from the value in register x9.  If this were the instruction, the next question is what program entity is currently occupying x9?  lldb might know, you can ask it by doing:

(lldb) image lookup -va $pc

That will tell you everything lldb knows about that pc, among other things the last set of entries will be where all the known variables are currently located.  Look for one that is in x9.  If there isn't one listed in x9, then maybe one of the currently visible variables was temporarily copied into x9, in which case you have to look up in the instruction stream to see what was the last value that got copied into x9.

Comment: thank you for this amazing answer. Check this one please: https://imgur.com/a/zbBMXus Does this means the crash is coming from `channel` variable ? Am I getting this right ?

Comment: Yes.  All 64 bit Darwin systems mask out the first 32 bits of memory (to catch 64 -> 32 bit truncation errors).  So if you ever see a memory address that's smaller than 0xffffffff on a Darwin system, that must be a bad pointer value.  So `channel` does not look good...